# How to get invoice link for a specific order in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, invoice

we are showing user meta data and orders detail as well link to user order through $order-get_order_url(). But i can't find anything like this for invoices. Is it possible to get invoice link through order number or id.
[meta data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTU6K.png)

Thanks and Best regards

Comment: Hi, do you have a slution?

Comment: Hy we tried this and it worked 
 `<?php
                        $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );
                        if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                            foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>`

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Shaamii** and his Code above, I figured it out how to display only the invoice link!

In **@Shaamii** code, the order and all invoices are output as a link.

If you edit the invoice in the backend then this and the final invoice are displayed as a link.

But I only need the last **invoice** and not the cancellation.

Here is my code:

```
$actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );      
echo $order_invoice = end($actions)['url'];
```